# google play services are not being imported into eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, google-play-services

I have google play services installed in my SDK directory but if I try to import it from this path `D:\andriod_sdk\extras\google\google_play_services`then I'm getting the error "No projects are found to import". Neither copying the  Google play services directory to desktop or copying it to my workspace or even creating a new workspace in eclipse had helped me to solve the problem.

[image]

[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Switch your workspace only....
click on File --> Switch Workspace -->change their workplace position